# Disable a button inside ion-nav-buttons

Tags: ionic-framework

How can I disable a button inside ion-nav-buttons depending on an action in the ion-content?

> example: if I click in a button inside ion-content the button inside
>   ion-nav-buttons get disabled.

As I see, I can´t controll the elements inside ion-nav-buttons from the controller of the template that has the ion-nav-buttons.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with **ng-disabled** in button

Check this [Try ng-disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_html_disabled)

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
      <button class="button" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="doSomething()">
        I'm a button on the primary of the navbar!
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
      <button class="button" ng-click="disable()">
        Click to disable
      </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

//Angular code

```
$scope.disable=function(){

  $scope.disabled=true;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @rashidnk, but I made the wrong question. I want to enable the ion-nav-buttons button when the form is valid. Any idea?

Comment: This is the answer is for ur qstion, you can accept as answer or voteup  and post ur new question, thanks